# html page will not render in android api 8 webview but OK in browser

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I am working on a simple android app to display a different page for each day of the week.

I have an HTML file I generated with Microsoft Word by saving as Web Page Filtered.

It renders OK in a WebView with API 17.

It renders OK in the Browser on API 8.

But, in the WebView in API 8, it gets reported  as "Web page not available" and then apparently it lists the text of the reply after

```
"The Web page at " blah "might be temporarily down, 
or..(more misdirection to useless impossibilities)"
```

where blah looks like the correct characters of the HTML I want it to render (not a URL at all)!  I wish I could paste that... well maybe I can if I stop in the debugger.....

The HTML includes what I think is a big comment.  If I edit out that comment manually, then it renders OK in API 8 WebView!

Is there some magic in this comment?  Or does it violate some comment rule that Microsoft does not know about?

I appreciate any insight if you have seen and solved a similar problem.

I will paste the failing HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Consolas;
    panose-1:2 11 6 9 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
p.MsoPlainText, li.MsoPlainText, div.MsoPlainText
    {mso-style-link:"Plain Text Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:10.5pt;
    font-family:Consolas;}
span.PlainTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Plain Text Char";
    mso-style-link:"Plain Text";
    font-family:Consolas;}
p.msochpdefault, li.msochpdefault, div.msochpdefault
    {mso-style-name:msochpdefault;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
p.msopapdefault, li.msopapdefault, div.msopapdefault
    {mso-style-name:msopapdefault;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 75.1pt 1.0in 75.05pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoPlainText><b><span style='font-size:28.0pt;font-family:"Courier New"'>Wednesday</span></b></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><b><span style='font-size:28.0pt;font-family:"Courier New"'>Mothra</span></b><span
style='font-size:28.0pt;font-family:"Courier New"'> will be here today from
10:00 to 4:00</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>&nbsp;</span></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

That looks OK I guess!  (my first post here).

The java is simple, but it could be the problem I suppose:

```
  case QueryService.STATUS_FINISHED:
            String results = resultData.getString("results");
            // jcb changed
            // mResponseContent.setText(results);
            wv.loadData(results, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", YOUR_HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Well that worked really well to solve my problem!  I wish I could get some clue WHY!  Could there be something in that comment that requires a base URL?  And why a blank one?  Does an empty string mean something different than null?  Why only a problem in API 8?  Thanks again!

Comment: Use the documentation: loadData: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 and loadDataWithBaseURL http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 loadData maybe won't work in API 8 with some html, remember that this Android API and webView is very old and for sincerity I never programming for this version.

Comment: Even in 2020 this answer helped me working with "MS Word generated HTML" from 2016. Thanks